# Increasing "show x items per page" does not working on SuperUser

Tags: bug, status-completed

I wanted to show 50 items per page in the *Unanswered Questions* page (default: 15).
After clicking the corresponding button, no questions are shown (blank left column). Same with the button for showing 30 questions. <strike>This works on the other three sites.</strike> (See Edit 2. Now it's reproducible on all sites)
It's not a caching problem.

I'm using Firefox 3.0 and Vista 64bit

**Edit**
Ian Elliott's link is working:
https://superuser.com/unanswered/tagged?page=1&tab=votes&pagesize=50
That's the link generated on my request:
https://superuser.com/unanswered/tagged?page=12&tab=votes&pagesize=50

There is page=12, not page=1 for some reason.

**Edit 2**
Now I understand the bug:
With show=15 I was on the 12th page (*go to page x* on the lower left). Here I changed the list to 50 items per page. Because a 12th page does not exits when 50 items are listed, I get no questions listed at all.

Comment: How is this bug "By Design"?

Comment: By Design in that the maths works out showing 30 items across 3 pages drops a page if the first two now show 50 items, they leave nothing for the last page.

Comment: Nice that the math works, but I think they should set page=1 if this happens. Sorry, Jeff, but 'by design' is pretty lame.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff, for finally fixing this :)

Comment: I still have this exact problem on StackOverflow. 50 questions per page lists only 16, 25 per page lists 9, and 10 per page lists 8. It only happens when I'm logged in, and is reproducible with Chrome v4.0.249.4 and Firefox 3.0.15. I have a load of ignore-tags. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely working for me, perhaps try direct [link](https://superuser.com/unanswered/tagged?page=1&tab=votes&pagesize=50)?
I don't see how this could be browser/OS specific as the info comes from the server. Otherwise I would argue that it *is* a cache problem.

Comment: I always add my system when posting bugs. Even if I think it is not the problem.